# Union contains a set $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a finite collection of open discs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose union contains a set $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that there is a pairwise disjoint subcollection $D_1,\ldots,D_n$ in $\mathcal{F}$ such that $$E\subseteq\cup_{j=1}^n 3D_j$$ Here, if $D$ is the disc of radius $r$ and center $P$, then $3D$ is the disc of radius $3r$ and center $P$.

Attemp: Consider closed disks $A$ and $B$ of equal radius and tangent to each other. Then $B \subset 3A$.

Am I right?

Comment: This is [Vitali's covering lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma). The proof is not a one-liner.

Comment: @Bungo http://www.math.wustl.edu/~sk/books/root.pdf  Can i use the proof of the Wiener's covering lemma, used in measure theory? (page 106 )